# Espresso waiting for textview

Tags: android, socket.io, android-espresso

I have a service that is connecting to a Socket.IO server. It is a simple app that sends a message and it gets echoed back to the client. I have a test as follows:

```
@Test
public void checkSendMessage() {

    final String testMessage = "Here is a test message";

    onView(withId(R.id.textEntry)).perform(typeText(testMessage), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.send)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.messages)).check(matches(withText(containsString(testMessage))));
}
```

I have the server running on my local network, and in this scenario everything runs and passes. However, if I add a 3 second delay in the server, then the test fails. I want to basically say wait for up to X seconds and then check if it contains the text.

I have seen similar questions with people answering to use an IdlingResource. However I am not sure how to integrate this into my app. I guess I have to implement the isIdleNow function. I am using a service that connects to com.koushikdutta.async.http.socketio.SocketIOClient;

It doesn't ever go idle though, it just sits there listening on the socket. So I am not really waiting for something to finish, I just want to keep checking the view for up to X seconds to see if a message arrived. How might I do this?

Answer (score 6):

I have solved it by writing a custom IdlingResource that checks the view assertion on every isIdleNow and eventually times out as per the code below:

```
@Test
public void checkSendMessage() {

    final String testMessage = "Here is a test message";

    onView(withId(R.id.textEntry)).perform(typeText(testMessage), closeSoftKeyboard());
    onView(withId(R.id.send)).perform(click());

    waitFor(onView(withId(R.id.messages)), matches(withText(containsString(testMessage))), 5000);
}

private void waitFor(ViewInteraction viewInteraction, ViewAssertion viewAssertion, long timeout) {

    PollingTimeoutIdler idler = new PollingTimeoutIdler(viewInteraction, viewAssertion, timeout);
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(idler);

    viewInteraction.check(viewAssertion);

    Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idler);
}

private class PollingTimeoutIdler implements IdlingResource {

    private final ViewAssertion mViewAssertion;
    private final long mTimeout;
    private final long mStartTime;
    private ResourceCallback mCallback;
    private volatile View mTestView;

    public PollingTimeoutIdler(ViewInteraction viewInteraction, ViewAssertion viewAssertion, long timeout) {
        mViewAssertion = viewAssertion;
        mTimeout = timeout;
        mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        viewInteraction.check(new ViewAssertion() {
            @Override
            public void check(View view, NoMatchingViewException noViewFoundException) {
                mTestView = view;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {

        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime;
        boolean timedOut = elapsed >= mTimeout;

        boolean idle = testView() || timedOut;
        if(idle) {
            mCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
        }

        return idle;
    }

    private boolean testView() {

        if(mTestView != null) {
            try {
                mViewAssertion.check(mTestView, null);
                return true;
            }
            catch(AssertionFailedError ex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }
}
```

It works but surely there is a better way? This feels super hacky and something Espresso should provide me. The fact that it doesn't leads me to believe I am thinking the wrong way about this test. Is there a better way to test the same behaviour?

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I modified it for my needs! This one waits for the number of children of a linear layout to be greater than zero. The children are added dynamically and we need to make sure at least one is there! https://gist.github.com/Emeritus-DarranKelinske/3ed580732dc36cebdb7bc9059e4a5efe

Comment: @Neo Ware why do you call  Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(idler); right after registering ? does that not unregister it right away ?