# React-native with android IdlindResources

Tags: android, react-native, automated-tests, android-espresso

Hi I'm trying to test mobile app written in react-native, i choose espresso + java to automate the process because [detox](https://github.com/wix/detox) has no support for android platform.

Target platform: android

Right now I'm struggling with timeouts in test namely:

- usage of simple onView always throws NoMatchingViewException
- Thread.sleep causes test to become flaky
- the best solution I've discovered so far is to use PollingTimeoutIdler from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112443/espresso-waiting-for-textview) post,
  but it seems to be flaky as well and depends on max timeout provided explicitly and the tests are just too slow.

Do you know the best way to write e2e test for react-native?
Maybe espresso is not the tool to use in that case.

Another idea was to use componentDidMount() in react to send information about component (if it finished rendering?) to java tests but I don't know if that's even possible.

Can you please help me ?

Best Regards.